TypeScript Build Errors on Render.com - "Cannot find module 'express'" and Other Type Issues
I'm trying to deploy my Node.js + TypeScript project on Render.com, but I'm encountering several TypeScript build errors that I don't see locally. The errors are mostly about missing modules and type definitions. Here are some of the errors I'm getting:
src/routers/mock/mock.ts(14,33): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
src/routers/mock/mock.ts(28,19): error TS2339: Property 'mock_settings' does not exist on type 'IOngoingJob'.
src/routers/mock/mock.ts(32,42): error TS2339: Property 'started_at' does not exist on type 'IOngoingJob'.
src/routers/ongoing-jobs-state.ts(1,61): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routers/ongoing-jobs.ts(1,61): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express' or its corresponding type declarations.
Everything works perfectly fine locally. Here's a snippet of my package.json:

{
  "name": "roro-fume-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "author": "Yanay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.1",
    "roro-fume": "^0.0.29",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.12",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.10",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}

And here's my tsconfig.json:
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es2020", "esnext.asynciterable", "dom"]
  }
}

Local Development: Works perfectly with no issues.
Deployment Environment: Render.com.
Why might TypeScript be unable to find modules and type declarations on Render.com but not locally?
Are there any additional configurations or steps I should take to ensure the build works on Render.com?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
